# Проблема чтении JSON на сервере node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Сервер не распознает JSON, приходящий от клиента.
Из этого поля `<input type="text" id="message">` я отправляю данные посредством `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("POST", "/publish", true);
var data = JSON.stringify({message: message.value});
 xhr.send(data);
```

Вот что на сервере (использую *Express*):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
/*   code     */
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  // Использую модуль body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());               // для чтения request.body

app.post("/publish", function(req, res){
var msg = req.body.message;

    chat.publish(msg);
    console.log(msg);
    res.send(msg);
});
```

На клиенте `console.log` говорит, что данные из `input` превращаются правильно. Т.е. если я введу "*something*", то строка, которая будет отправляться на сервер, имеет вид `{"message":"something"}`.
На сервере `console.log` говорит, что `undefined`.
НО. Отправляя данные, используя стороннюю утилиту для запросов (Postman), такого же вида `{"message":"something"}`, сервер распознает `message`.
Что может быть не так?

Comment: Проставлять правильные заголовки запроса пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

[Body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) обрабатывает (или не обрабатывает) запросы на основании значения заголовка [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

Для JSON запросов этот заголовок должен принимать значение:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Вот пример того, как можно задать правильное значение этого заголовка на клиенте:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/publish", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({message: message.value}));
```